# Only mkdir if it does not exist

Tags: bash, unix

In my bash script I do:

```
mkdir product;
```

When I run the script more than once I get:

```
mkdir: product: File exists
```

In the console.

So I am looking to only run mkdir if the dir doesn't exist.  Is this possible?

Comment: mkdir product 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Do a test

```
[[ -d dir ]] || mkdir dir
```

Or use -p option:

```
mkdir -p dir
```

Comment: I can't find the source on the fly, but for Makefiles `mkdir -p`  is discouraged b/c there may be race conditions in concurrent execution. So, depending on what your script does and in which environment it lives the first option given is this answer should be preferred. Also, you could just `mkdir product 2>/dev/null` and not care.

Comment: @user1129682: The first option also has a potential race condition; the directory could be created by some other process between the `-d` test and the `mkdir`. I suspect `mkdir -p` makes this time window for this race condition slightly shorter.

Comment: Beside the race condition in the innecessary testing, there is also the possibility that `dir` does exist **but is not a directory**, but a file or a device entry or a unix-domain socket or a named pipe, or _whatever_ ...

Comment: @wildplasser Yes and that would already be in the coder's option how he/she would handle the situation. One could send a message to the user and ask for input, abort, or do other things if `[[ -e dir && ! -d dir ]]` is valid.

Comment: Useful and concise, +1 :)

Comment: Anyway, you should just have in mind @andy-lester 's remark in the answer below.

Answer (score 152):

```
if [ ! -d directory ]; then
  mkdir directory
fi
```

or

```
mkdir -p directory
```

`-p` ensures creation if `directory` does not exist

Comment: One-liner requires an extra `;`: `if [ ! -d directory ]; then mkdir directory; fi`

Answer (score 12):

Use mkdir's `-p` option, but note that it has another effect as well.

```
 -p      Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is not specified, the full path prefix of each oper-
         and must already exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no error will be reported if a directory
         given as an operand already exists.  Intermediate directories are created with permission bits of rwxrwxrwx
         (0777) as modified by the current umask, plus write and search permission for the owner.
```

Answer (score 5):

`mkdir -p`

> -p, --parents
>                 no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Answer (score 5):

Try using this:-

```
mkdir -p dir;
```

**NOTE:-** This will also create any intermediate directories that don't exist; for instance,

Check out [mkdir -p](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkdir.html)

or try this:-

```
if [[ ! -e $dir ]]; then
    mkdir $dir
elif [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
    echo "$Message" 1>&2
fi
```

Comment: FYI : `-e` stands for "file exists" and `-d` stands for "is a directory"